# Which one is bigger? Logarithms and trigonometric functions

Tags: inequality, asymptotics, number-comparison

There's the problem: 
given that $0<\alpha<\beta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ ,   what is bigger

$$\frac{\ln(\cos\alpha)-\ln(\cos\beta)}{\beta-\alpha}$$ 
or
$$\tan(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})$$
I tried to simplify a little bit the first term. Now its $$\frac{\ln(\frac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\beta})}{\beta-\alpha}$$. 
Than I tried raise $e$ to the power of both sides and see If I can prove what's bigger, but it was not working. Can someone help please? 
Thanks!

Comment: In the limit $\beta\rightarrow \alpha$ the first expression is the derivative of $-\ln(\cos \alpha)$, which happens to be $\tan\alpha$, so they are equal. If whatever the relationship between the two expression holds for any $\alpha$ and $\beta$, try $\alpha=\pi/6$ and $\beta=\pi/3$. The first expression is finite, the second is $\infty$

Comment: @Andrei. I have the feeling that, in your example, you missed the division by $2$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Where? $\tan\frac{\alpha+\alpha}{2}=\tan\alpha$

Comment: @Andrei. OK but $\alpha < \frac \pi 2$

Comment: $\pi/6<\pi/2$ and $\pi/3<\pi/2$. The cosine value for both is finite and greater than $0$, so the first expression is finite. The second one is $\tan (\pi/6+\pi/3)=\tan(\pi/2)=\infty$

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to perform Taylor expansions built at $\beta=\alpha$ assuming that $\beta-\alpha$ is small.

This would give, after trigonometric simplifications, 
$$A=\frac{\log (\cos (\alpha ))-\log (\cos (\beta ))}{\beta -\alpha }=\tan (\alpha )+\frac{1}{2} (\beta -\alpha ) \sec ^2(\alpha )+\frac{1}{3} (\beta
   -\alpha )^2 \tan (\alpha ) \sec ^2(\alpha )+O\left((\beta -\alpha )^3\right)$$
$$B=\tan \left(\frac{\alpha +\beta }{2}\right)=\tan (\alpha )+\frac{1}{2} (\beta -\alpha ) \sec ^2(\alpha )+\frac{1}{3} (\beta
   -\alpha )^2 \tan (\alpha ) \sec ^2(\alpha )+O\left((\beta -\alpha )^3\right)$$

Now the difference between the first and the second is
$$\Delta=A-B=\frac{1}{12} (\beta -\alpha )^2 \tan (\alpha ) \sec ^2(\alpha )+O\left((\beta
   -\alpha )^3\right)$$ and since $\beta > \alpha$, then $\cdots$